# Force Visual Studio to open unknown filetypes as plain text

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a file with the extension `.tcts` with the following contents

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    var someServerSideJSVariable = "";
[%
    Dim someVBVariable
    someVBVariable = "";
%]
</script>
<%
    If true Then
%>
    <div>some html</div>
<%
    End If
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someClientSideVariable = "";
</script>
```

Visual Studio 2012 tries to automatically determine the context and gives this view

[image: Visual Studio formatting]

This isn't helpful as the text is incorrectly coloured and there are red error lines on code that is valid. I would like to force Visual Studio to just open it as a plain text file. No intellisense. No automatic formatting.

I have looked at `Options > Text Editor > File Extension` but none of the Editor Options seem appropriate.

Is there something I can do to force Visual Studio to open `.tcts` files as plain text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look:

[image]

This helps: no intellisense, no automatic formatting.

Comment: This is what I did except it always asks for the file encoding when opening such a file. Which is equally annoying.